# Different tenses in different situations

Tags: present-perfect, present-progressive

Could you please tell me which one is correct (or which one is the correct one?) out of each set of sentences?
None of them are from a quiz or a practice. These are sentences that I've tried to made in last 24 hours.

---

I've been laughing too much lately.

I am laughing too much lately.

---

I have had a surgery on my eyes so I can't tolerate the sunlight.

I had a surgery on my eyes so I can't tolerate the sunlight.

(which on is more proper in this sentence, bear or tolerate or stand)

---

I had knocked on the door before coming inside.

I had knocked on the door before I came in.

---

I haven't any dictionary installed on my phone.

I haven't got any dictionary installed on my phone.

I haven't installed any dictionary on my phone.

---

Did you take my shoe?

Have you taken my shoe?

---

I really appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been laughing too much recently.

I had surgery on my eyes so I can't tolerate the sunlight. (Note no "a".)

Either of the choices in the third set are probably fine, but the first sounds old-fashioned to my ear. I would also consider "I don't have a dictionary installed on my phone."

Either of the choices in the fourth set are fine, although the connotations are perhaps slightly different.

Comment: When I was young, say fifty years ago _I don't have_ was distinctly American, and in Britain we said _I haven't got_, or more formally _I haven't_. But _I don't have_ has been gradually gaining ground here.

Comment: @Coline Fine: I should thank both of you a lot for your help. I think the most important thing is how a sentence sounds in a native speaker ears.